# EntityFramework Core issue after deleting Migrations folder

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I did some migrations and updated database and everything was good. Then I deleted the Migrations folder. After that when i type`EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration Initial` the new migration is empty.
***Initial.cs:***

```
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
```

I also tried to create new database but still old migrations exist somewhere, so I can't create new one.

How to create Initial migration in this case?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the model snapshot?

Comment: @mesies Yes I did

Comment: I fixed it by removing all EFCore NuGet packages and installing them once again